# source code for the pickProcess command VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

When selecting a processID using `"${command:pickProcess}"`, you would get a list of .exe files that the debugger can attach to in VS Code

Is there a way to get the source code for the pickProcess command variable?

Comment: have you searched the repo

Comment: @rioV8 He/she is likely to have searched, but the keyword won't hit since the actual process selection goes to individual debugging related classes.

Comment: @LexLi Just like you he/she could have found it too